# dictation recognition session won't start even after PhraseRecognitionSystem is disposed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On Unity I am testing keyword recognition and dictation recognizer with following  functions assigned on two buttons.

Unity doc says Phrase Recognition system wont start with Dictation recognition system but it doesn't mention it on keyword recognizer's article. And in this test everything working but even if I start the keyword recognizer and dispose it on next click, on the other button click dictation recognizer wont start and shows following error:

```
Cannot start dictation recognition session while PhraseRecognitionSystem is running.
```

Here's the code for OnButtonClick method of first button:

```
           if(start != true){    
            m_Recognizer.Stop();
            m_Recognizer.Dispose();
            Debug.Log("disposed recognizer.");
            start = true;
            } //start on else...;
```

Here's code for starting dictation recognizer:

```
        m_DictationRecognizer = new DictationRecognizer();

        m_DictationRecognizer.DictationResult += M_DictationRecognizer_DictationResult;


        m_DictationRecognizer.DictationHypothesis += (text) =>
        {

            Debug.LogFormat("Dictation hypothesis: {0}", text);
            m_Hypotheses.text = text;

        };
        //here happens mentioned exception.
               m_DictationRecognizer.Start();
```

I need to know How to properly dispose the keyword recognizer object and how to properly start m_DictaionRecognizer and Can both of this be run simultaneously?

Thanks.

Comment: I know from personal experience that this API is awful and unreliable. It seems the system are asynchronously stopped at some point in time, but it is rarely immediately after the call to `Stop()`. An ugly workaround I have used is to poll for the Status of the `PhraseRecognitionSystem` in a coroutine, and `yield return null` while the Status is still `Running`. Only after that, I did not get an exception when trying to start a `DictationRecognizer`. This works vice-versa as well. It's ugly as hell but it's the best solution I have so far.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your valuable experience. It would be great if any code example or link is available to manipulate PhraseRecognitionSystem's status, and  Do you think with such approach we can run both of this simultaneously?

Comment: It is impossible to run both systems at once, unfortunately. This is restricted by Windows itself, and conceptually also makes sense. I will create a small gist and link it here shortly.

Comment: That will be nice. Thank you.

Comment: Try something like [this](https://gist.github.com/Kwintenvdb/c9fabc3d131fa34161f19abd26484184). It's ugly but does the trick for me. Obviously substitute with your own variables and whatnot.

Comment: Hi. It would be great if I could stop the coroutine. Currently the I'm trying with stopAllCoroutine method from other class that is called after the dictation rec. started, but the following message keeps going on. The msg: ` Assertion failed: Assertion failed on expression: 'NULL != cur'
UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.PhraseRecognitionSystem:Shutdown();`  Do you think stopping it is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Using both system have no sense.
Anyway if you want to restart the DictationRecognizer, reinitialize it completely, by writing your second snippet code in a function, and call this function in your "start code" for the launch of reconizing.

The best options is to dont stop either dispose your DictationRecognizer, and handle the regognized sentense to a REGEX.

```
if( Regex.IsMatch(DictationResult.text, "mykeyword", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) )
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stopping and disposing m_recognizer does not stop the PhraseRecognitionSystem. I won't claim that I understand the distinction but adding this line under m_recognizer.Dispose() worked for me:

PhraseRecognitionSystem.Shutdown();

I do not see any equivalent for a recognition system to shut down for dictation, so should be no need to worry about that if switching back from dictation to keyword recognition.

Just to be safe, when transitioning I also Stop, Dispose, and unsubscribe from all the event listeners. Then reinstantiate the new recognizer fresh, and re-subscribe to the listeners.

Answer (score 0):

If Dictation Recognizer suddenly stops working, please add this line when you create dictation recognizer:

dictationRecognizer.AutoSilenceTimeoutSeconds = 5f;

Also remember to shutdown PhraseRecognitionSystem when you start the dictation recognizer